# Custom path for my libraries for find_library

Tags: cmake

I am trying to compile [openimageio](https://sites.google.com/site/openimageio/)(oiio) on Linux but it's a mess since I know almost nothing about `cmake`. I don't want and I can't install them on my computer directly in the `/usr/local/` directory and that's the problem. I successfully compiled dependencies by executing these bash commands in each library directory :

```
export workingdir=<path_to_my_project>
./configure --prefix=$workingdir/sdks/deploy
make install
```

And this works fine, my headers are in a `include` directory and my libraries are in a `lib` directory.

Here is the structure of my project :

```
../<path_to_my_project>
   /sdks
      /build
        /oiio
        /png   # Successfully compiled
        /jpeg  # Successfully compiled
        /zlib  # Successfully compiled
        /boost # Successfully compiled
        /ilmbase # Successfully compiled
        /openexr # Successfully compiled
      /deploy
        /lib # all .a, .la and .so of successfully compiled libraries
        /include # all headers of successfully compiled libraries
```

The problem is that there is no `./configure` available in the oiio library directory so I don't know how to set the prefix path, when I execute the make command, I have errors like this :

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
Could NOT find PNG (missing: PNG_LIBRARY) (found version "1.6.21")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:315 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
   /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPNG.cmake:105 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
   src/libOpenImageIO/CMakeLists.txt:120 (find_package)
```

So I set variables and it makes no errors but this is not clean and I'm not sure that my libraries are correctly referenced (If I mes up the variable content, it is still working...).

```
set (PNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR "<workingdir>/sdks/deploy/include/libpng16")
set (PNG_LIBRARY_DIR "<workingdir>/sdks/deploy/lib")
```

Then I tried to create my own `FindXXX.cmake` files but some don't have a Root variable for the library so anyway I'm not sure if it correctly found the needed files, moreover, it makes errors :

```
CMake Error at src/cmake/modules/FindPNG.cmake:104 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    <workingdir>/sdks/build/oiio/src/cmake/modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/libOpenImageIO/CMakeLists.txt:120 (find_package)
```

But it finds the `cmake` file it anyway since other errors are correctly referenced to my file and if I print something in the `cmake` file it shows up when I run the `make` command.

Up to know, the command I am running in the oiio directory is `make` but I would like something that tells to the `find_library` function to looks other where. I could recall the function with other parameters but I can't use my own FindXXX.cmake files.

In the oiio repository, in the [INSTALL](https://github.com/OpenImageIO/oiio/blob/master/INSTALL) file, paragraph line 43, it says to set environment variable for custom libraries, like `PNGDIR`, but should it point to the deploys directory or the build directory ? And they say to see CMake configuration output, maybe to know what environment variables to set, but I don't know what file they are talking.

I tried so set PNGDIR but it doesn't work, how to know if the variable name should be PNGDIR ? It can also be PNGROOT ?

```
export PNGDIR=<workingdir>/sdks/deploy  # doesn't work
export PNGDIR=<workingdir>/sdks/build/png  # doesn't work
```

It would be nice if someone could help me, I need this library to be compiled to use it, hope someone understood me.

Comment: Use `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. Stuff like `PNGDIR` should no longer be used.

Comment: It seems to work, I have new errors now, much comprehensible, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to indicate paths where `find_library`, `find_path` et al. should have a look ([documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html))

Stuff like `PNGDIR` should no longer be used and is considered legacy that is kept for backwards compatibility. Patches for FindXXX provided by CMake to add `XXX_DIR` or `XXX_ROOT` are rejected by the CMake developers.